# How to include two different PIP versions of pyyaml in my code?

Tags: python, pip, dependencies, pyyaml

i'm having an issue with my code. I wrote code that uses two object detection libraries (detectron and detectron2). I have them both imported.

```
from Detectron
from Detectron2
```

The issue is that Detectron requires PYYAML == 3.X
while Detectron2 requires PYYAML == 5.1.

So when I try to run the program, I have to either update/downgrade the PYYAML version. How do I fix this issue? How can I import both libraries?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you *can't* have two versions of the same package. This is not a Pip issue, actually this is more like a Python limitation (Python itself doesn't support things like that). See https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10352 for more information.